# Search array for listview filtering - Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, class, dart, search, types

I am trying to integrate a search and filter textfield in my app, but I am not completely sure of the errors my compiler is throwing. I think I am having type issues, or that I have not set up my inheritances correctly?
Ok, so basically I am sending a http request to an api and receiving this data where I have set up my class  to display it. In a futurebuilder I have some conditional logic trying to sort the right data I need into separate lists(Im not sure if this the right thing to do but I digress) I then create a map (resultMap) and within that I loop through the arrays and nest a map (innerMap).

```
     class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
      final controller = TextEditingController();
      String? searchString = '';
      late final Future<ProjectModel> futureProjects;

      List<ProjectSearch> searchList = []; //I think this causing this issues.....
      List<String?> jobNames = [];
      List<String?> jobNumbers = [];
      List<String?> techs = [];
      List<String?> pms = [];
      List<String?> address = [];
      List<String?> majors = [];
      List<String?> budget = [];
      Map resultMap = {};

      @override
       void initState() {
       super.initState();
       futureProjects = fetchProjects();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
           title: const Text(
           'Upcoming / Live Projects',
           style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 18,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: ColorConstants.darkScaffoldBackgroundColor,
      ),
      drawer: const CustomDrawer(),
      backgroundColor: ColorConstants.lightScaffoldBackgroundColor,

      // ignore: avoid_unnecessary_containers
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<ProjectModel>(
            future: futureProjects,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                var data = snapshot.data!;
                var columns = data.columns;
                var rows = data.rows;

                for (var item in rows!) {
                  var cells = item.cells;
                  for (var elements in cells!) 
                    if (elements.columnId != null) {
                      if (elements.columnId == 2057691532158852) {
                        var displayValues = elements.displayValue;
                        if (displayValues != null) {
                          jobNames.add(displayValues);
                        }
                       ..... continuing conditional logic

     //Here is where I nest my arrays to the resultMap map:
                int index = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < jobNames.length; i++) {
                  Map innerMap = {};

                  innerMap['name'] = jobNames[index];
                  innerMap['address'] = address[index];
                  innerMap['jobNumber'] = jobNumbers[index];
                  innerMap['major'] = majors[index];
                  innerMap['tech'] = techs[index];
                  innerMap['pM'] = pms[index];
                  innerMap['budget'] = budget[index];

                  index++;
                  resultMap[i] = innerMap;
                }
```

I have been looking trough some tutorials and it looks like it is easier to apply string search functions using .contains() but these only work on lists. So I convert my resultMap using a forEach to create my searchList list.

```
                resultMap.forEach((key, value) => searchList.add(value));
```

Here is my TextFormField:

```
                   TextFormField(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          controller: controller,
                          onChanged: search,
                          .....
```

And then my ListView.builder:

```
                    return MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () => showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                     context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              final projectData = searchList[index];
                    return 
                          Text(
                             projectData['name'],
```

And finally the function I am using to search:

```
     void search(String query) {
       List finder = searchList;

        final suggestions = searchList.where((check) {
        final projectName = check['name'].toLowerCase();
        final input = query.toLowerCase();

         return projectName.contains(input);
         }).toList();

          setState(() {
           finder = suggestions;
          });
     }
```

I hope this makes sense...
When I get rid of the  model it doesn't break down but the search function doesnt filter thru the array. However here is the compile error:

```
    type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ProjectModel>' of 'function 
     result'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem arises when you convert **map to list**. please try below procedure to convert map to list when data comes from api...
obviously do anything(search) with list data in your app.
just change api url from below

```
 Future<List<ProjectModel>> fetchProjectData() async {
        final response =
            await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
          // then parse the JSON.
          final parsed = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
          return parsed.map<ProjectModel>((json) => ProjectModel.fromJson(json)).toList();
        } else {
          // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
          // then throw an exception.
          throw Exception('Failed to load data');
        }
      }
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I have sorted out my issues with my type casting. I was trying to add String Lists into my ProjectSearch model and it was causing all types of issues that were confusing.... Now I have all that sorted and Im getting the search bar to generate search items but it is displaying duplicate items..... and also a bit slow to react

Comment: u have to clear list before adding searching fresh data into the same list

Comment: I have called .clear() in my setState but my listView is duplicating items?? I am also trying to call .toSet().toList() but it doesnt seem to change the amount of duplications.

Comment: is it because I am looking up list objects?